# Mac: print pdf to apple note

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

I am trying to move from using Evernote to apple note.

One function that I am missing is from the print menu on a mac to be able to save the PDF to a new note.

I figured that I can create a print_plugin from Automator. I am trying to have an apple script handling the creation of a new note. Googling and using my limited knowledge of apple script I figured that I need to do something like

```
property accountName : "iCloud"
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Preview"
        open input
    end tell
    tell application "Notes"
        
        activate
        set theFolder to choose from list ((name of folders of account accountName) as list)
        if theFolder is not false then
            set newNote to make new note in folder (item 1 of theFolder) of account accountName
            if input is not {} then
                tell newNote
                    make new attachment with input
                    show
                end tell
            end if
        end if
    end tell
end run
```

The preview part of the code is to see if the pdf is passed correctly. Preview can indeed open the pdf correctly.

When I run the script I get the following error

```
The action “Run AppleScript” encountered an error: “Notes got an error: Can’t make show id "x-coredata://726D28C7-1847-43DA-9A8D-A9A1B379DF6F/ICNote/p6780" into type specifier.”

Notes got an error: Can’t make show id "x-coredata://726D28C7-1847-43DA-9A8D-A9A1B379DF6F/ICNote/p6780" into type specifier
```

If I remove the line
`make new attachment with input`
the script runs without error (but clearly no attachment is created).

Does anyone have a solution?

Best,
E

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a lot of meddling I found this sort of solution:

```
property accountName : "iCloud"
on run {input, parameters}
  tell application "Notes"
    open input
  end tell
end run
```

When saved as a print plugin, it creates a new note with the title of the webpage and the pdf attached. It creates it in the "Notes" folder, which works fine for me.

Best,

E